# ERROR: syntax Error At or Near "update"

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to create a new column in my parks database then calculate the area of the park but i keep getting this syntax error.

Can anyone see what is wrong with it?

```
alter table parks add column area double precision update parks set area = select st_area(geom) * power(0.3048,2) from parks;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one problem here:

1. You should split it into 2 queries
2. There shouldn't be a SELECT in your UPDATE
3. Use a fixed number for the multiply, you might run the risk that your power
   is calculated over and over

Here's the query that should work:

```
ALTER TABLE parks ADD COLUMN area double precision;

UPDATE parks SET area = st_area(geom) * 0.09290304;
```